# Move property to new Entity in Entity Framework Code First Migration

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework Code First approach in my project. I have a problem with database migration.

Now I have the entity

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I have already have data in my existing DataBase. Now I want to extend City property, like this

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

so, City become to Location with many properties.

```
public partial class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
}
```

So, I need for each row in Events Table create row in Locations Table and copy city. And set foreign key for event localtion to location row.But I don't know how to move existing data using Entity Framework Migration. I have read many post on Entity Framework Migration, but didn't find this case.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that in 3 steps

- Add Location
- Insert Location
- Drop City

Starting from

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

- Add Location property and class
- Add Location migration and update the database

  `PM> Enable-Migrations`

  `PM> Add-Migration AddLocationTable`

  `PM> Update-Database`
- Create empty migration for inserting the data

  `PM> Add-Migration InsertLocationData`

  The class should have empty `Up` and `Down` method.
  Add following code in the `Up` method.

  ```
  using (var context = new AppContext())
  {
      var events = context.Set<Event>().ToArray();
      foreach (var ev in events)
      {
          ev.Location = new Location { City = ev.City };
      }
      context.SaveChanges();
  }
  ```
- Run the migration again to apply `InsertLocationData` migration.

  `PM> Update-Database`
- Delete `City` property and run a migration to apply the changes.

  `PM> Add-Migration DropCityFromEvent`

  `PM> Update-Database`

Comment: @AdelNazirov, before doing the last step `delete city..`, make sure first that the location data and foreign keys are properly inserted / updated

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks! However, in my case, I must change my DbContext, because I am doing some massive refactoring. Locally, I can create the new tables and expand my DbContext (migration 1), copy the data to the new tables (migration 2), delete the old tables (migration 3), remove the old tables from the DbContext. However, when I will push this to the remote env, it will try to execute the migration 1, find a DbContext not aligned with the current model, and throw an exception. Do you know how to work around this? I would like to avoid pushing for each step (not a real solution...)