# Deleting a moved property in Entity Framework code first migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I need to move a code first Entity Framework property from one entity to another using migrations. This is similar to [Move property to new Entity in Entity Framework Code First Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093390/move-property-to-new-entity-in-entity-framework-code-first-migration), but with one extra wrinkle: I need to ship the migrations in my application so that customers with existing data can be migrated automatically.

The accepted answer in that question says to break the process into three migrations:

1. Add the new property
2. Move the data from the old property to the new property
3. Delete the old property

The code used to move data in the second migration is:

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    var events = context.Set<Event>().ToArray();
    foreach (var ev in events)
    {
        ev.Location = new Location { City = ev.City };
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is that when I delete the old property to generate the third migration, the code for the second migration will no longer compile because the property `ev.City` no longer exists.

What is the proper technique for deleting the property from both the code model and the database in the third migration, while still moving the data in the second migration? Is there a way to write the second migration code to move the data without referring to `ev.City`? Are there Entity Framework methods that will allow me to retrieve the value of `ev.City` without having a property with that name, or do I need to drop all the way down to raw SQL commands?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the context inside your migration. Instead I'd use this in the migration:

Sql("UPDATE x SET foo=bar");

Then it doesn't matter what your entities look like.

Comment: I think you may be right that I'll have to use SQL directly, but it's more complex than a simple UPDATE. The second migration code is also inserting new entities, so at a minimum it will take an INSERT ... SELECT statement. That would probably be faster than using a context, but it's also more error-prone. Thanks for pointing out the Sql function for use in migrations.

Comment: @StuartMalone the good news is that's it's pretty easy to test in raw SQL. Plus I believe anything you add will get wrapped in an automatic transaction.

Answer (score 1):

As @BigJump pointed out, it's probably bad practice to use a Context in a migration. The [DbMigration.Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql(v=vs.113).aspx) method allows arbitrary SQL to be included in a migration, and has several advantages over using a Context:

1. It is executed on the server, which is probably faster.
2. It is automatically put into the migration transaction, so the migration is atomic.
3. Since it does not require a context, it can be executed at the end of the first migration rather than requiring a separate migration.

In the example given, the statement

```
Sql("INSERT INTO Locations (Event_Id, City) SELECT Id, City FROM Events");
```

would be placed at the bottom of the Up method in the first migration.